# facebook REST API - infinite session key

Tags: facebook

How to get the infinite session key using facebook REST API (PHP)?

can someone show me a step by step code/procedure?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here is [how to create infinite sessions with the Facebook Platform API](http://www.henrycipolla.com/blog/2008/02/how-to-create-infinite-sessions-with-the-Facebook-platform-api/).

Answer (score 0):

Lets see this answer.Its code for Graph api but you have to check permission.You need to add offline access.

[Graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687770/do-facebook-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-expire/3519702#3519702)

Let me know its work or not.

Thanks