# facebook Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, facebook, api, access-token

I've been struggling to find out what is happening with this.
My scripts were working fine for a bit and suddenly half stopped.

I'm accessing the api and am getting back an access token. With the access token, I can access a users public info just fine. However, when I try to post info to their FB account I get this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Any idea what is happening here?
I'm also using sessions on my site to keep track of internal user ids. Not sure if my sessions could be causing a problem.

This is my upload script where I'm getting an error.

```
require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';


// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '12345678',
  'secret' => 'REMOVED',
  'fileUpload' => true, 
  'cookie' => true,
));
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); 

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}


// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


$photo_details = array('message' => 'my place');
$file='photos/my.jpg'; //Example image file
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just check for the current Facebook user id `$user` and if it returned null then you need to reauthorize the user (or use the custom `$_SESSION` user id value - not recommended)

```
require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';


// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$photo_details = array('message' => 'my place');
$file='photos/my.jpg'; //Example image file
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

if ($user) {
  try {
    // We have a valid FB session, so we can use 'me'
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}


// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
// redirect to Facebook login to get a fresh user access_token
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
}
```

I've written a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-a-photo-to-a-users-profile-using-facebook-graph-api/66/) on how to upload a picture to the user's wall.

Comment: +1 ... thanks for the answer.. was breaking my head on this... 'me' looks for a valid facebook session... whereas 'facebook user_id' does not.. just what I wanted

Comment: here we are checking for the permissions for the app?.First time it shown the facebook dialog for goto App.i have clicked it.After that now when i opens the page it shows blank page

Comment: @VIJESH, are you using the code above as is? you are aware that this is incomplete code just to get you started.

Comment: thankyou I have resolved my problem 50% right now please if you can help I have a similar topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632458/php-facebook-sdk-doesnt-create-the-user-in-wordpress :(

Answer (score 33):

## Use:

```
$facebook->api('/'.$facebook_uid)
```

**instead of**

```
$facebook->api('/me')
```

it works.

Comment: Its not a bug; as the first comment on the accepted answer says ... 'me' looks for a valid facebook session whereas 'facebook user_id' does not

Answer (score 18):

So I had the same issue, but it was because I was saving the access token but not using it.  It could be because I'm super sleepy because of due dates, or maybe I just didn't think about it! But in case anyone else is in the same situation:

When I log in the user I save the access token:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => <insert the app id you get from facebook here>,
    'secret' => <insert the app secret you get from facebook here>
));

$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
//save the access token for later
```

---

Now when I make requests to facebook I just do something like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => <insert the app id you get from facebook here>,
    'secret' => <insert the app secret you get from facebook here>
));

$facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$facebook->api(... insert own code here ...)
```

Comment: I love you for this answer! This saved me regarding an issue I had with the new Dec 5th breaking-changes. I was researching on this for days.

Comment: dear god, just spent 2 hours looking for this and I too forgot to set my saved token.  bleh.

Answer (score 4):

After a certain amount of time, your access token expires.

To prevent this, you can request the 'offline_access' permission during the authentication, as noted here: [Do Facebook Oauth 2.0 Access Tokens Expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687770/do-facebook-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-expire)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and the solution was to reauthorize the user.
Check it here:

```
<?php

 require_once("src/facebook.php");

  $config = array(
      'appId' => '1424980371051918',
      'secret' => '2ed5c1260daa4c44673ba6fbc348c67d',
      'fileUpload' => false // optional
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

//Authorizing app:

?>
<a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl(); ?>">Login con fb</a>
```

Saved project and opened on my test enviroment and it worked again. As I did, you can comment your previous code and try.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue when tried to get users information without auth.

Check if you have loggen in before any request.

```
 $uid = $facebook->getUser();

 if ($uid){
      $me = $facebook->api('/me');
 }
```

The code above should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I can solve this issue by cleaning the cookies and cache from my browser `(ctrl+shift+R)`. Also, you must ensure that your access token is active.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.