# problem api facebook v3

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [facebook Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034813/facebook-uncaught-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-in)

I have a problem with v3 of php api facebook.

This is the error:
OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

This is the code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId'  => 'xxxxx',
              'secret' => 'xxxxx',
            ));

            $user = $facebook->getUser();
            $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

            if ($user) {
                try {
                    $events = $facebook->api('/me');
                } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                    echo ($e);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must redirect to a login url, you can get the url with `getLoginUrl` method of facebook object:

```
if ($user) {
     // if accepted              
}else{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();  // redirect to this url.
}
```

When you accept the application, you'll get an access token and be able to use the api.

Comment: my code is execute when I click a button of my app.