# How to solve 'This method must be called with an app access_token' error?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I'm testing out scores api on my test app.

So...I've singed up my app with the following permissions.

```
publish_stream,
publish_actions,
user_status,
user_photos
```

After logged in, I'm requesting the following api in PHP

```
$loggedUser = $Facebook->getUser();
$scoreUpdate = $Facebook->api('/'.$loggedUser."/scores", 'post', array('score'=> 100));
```

I get the following error.

> This method must be called with an app access_token

So I've checked what the sdk is sending to facebook, and I've confirmed that it is sending 'access_token' along with my params.

What's the problem in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there are two tokens, a User token...and an [Application token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin). You need the later.

Now the PHP-SDK will append the user `access_token` if it finds one which is *I think* your case. I suggest you read the official Facebook [how-to for publishing scores](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/)

Example taken from my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-get-a-facebook-application-access-token/41/):

```
$APPLICATION_ID = "APP_ID";
$APPLICATION_SECRET = "APP_SECRET";

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID .
                "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET .
                "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

Comment: // ah..yes! that was the problem. Is it possible to get an Application token using facebook php sdk? stackoverflow is deleting @ifaour somehow...

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if granting the `manage_pages` and then calling `me/accounts` and getting the app `access_token` would be the same, but that would be so much work just for this. What do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: // i appreciate your answers. Ah...disregard my last sentence...I used "@ifaour", but stackoverflow keeps removing it from my comment.

Comment: by the way..your website is veeerrrrry helpful.

Comment: @Moon thanks! There will be a lot of changes and tutorials coming soon!

Answer (score 5):

app access_token you can simple make it like this:

`$facebook->api('/me/scores', 'POST', array(
  'score' => 100,
  'access_token' => $facebook->getAppId().'|'.$facebook->getApiSecret()
));`

voila

Answer (score 2):

```
$ret_obj = $fb->api( '/' . $fb->getUser() . '/scores', 'POST', array(
    'score' =>  100,
    'access_token' => $fb->getAppId().'|'.$fb->getApiSecret()
));
```

If you specify the app access token in the access_token parameter, you will eventually lose the ability to use /me, so you have to be specific about the user ID. Otherwise you get this error: "OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user", as explained here : [facebook Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034813/facebook-uncaught-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-i)