# Facebook login using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to login with FB using codeigniter & the FB PHP SDK.

but it keeps giving me the same login with facebook link, it's not catching if the user is logged in, Am I missing anything like sessions or something?

And since we are at it how can I get the extended session & what data should I save to publish to pages while user is offline?

here is my controller:

```
function __construct () {
    parent::__construct();      
    $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    $this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/facebook/');
    $this->config->load('facebook', TRUE);
    $this->load->library('facebook', array( 'appId'  => $this->config->item('appId', 'facebook'), 'secret' => $this->config->item('secret', 'facebook') ) );
}

public function index() {
    $data['LoginURL']   = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl( array('scope' => 'manage_pages') );
    $data['user']       = $this->facebook->getUser();
    if ($data['user']) {
      try {
        $data['user_profile']   = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        $data['AccessToken']    = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        // The access token we have is not valid
        $data['user'] = null;
      }
    }
    $this->load->view('fb_welcome', $data);
}
```

And here is the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>
<?php if ( $user ): ?>      
    User <em><?php echo $user ?></em> is Logged in, AccessToken is <?php echo $AccessToken; ?>
    <?php print_r($user_profile); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo anchor($LoginURL, "Login with facebook"); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know code igniter, but hopefully this should prove a good starting point, just link to your fb sdk in the include, replace the vars with your own and it should give the user a popup when they are not logged in:

```
// include the FB SDK
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/facebook/facebook.php');

// create the application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $this->facebookConfig->appid,
    'secret' => $this->facebookConfig->appsecret
));

// get the user id
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if(!empty($user)) {
    // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
    // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
    try {

        // do something

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $params = array(
            'scope'         => $this->permissions,
            'redirect_uri'  => $this->facebookConfig->applink
        );
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

        // log errors
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());

        // redirect if not logged in or not enough permissions
        //echo "<script>top.location=\"".$loginUrl."\";</script>";die;
    }

    // Give the user a logout link 
    //echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
} else {

    $params = array(
            'scope'         => $this->permissions,
            'redirect_uri'  => $this->facebookConfig->applink
        );
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

    // log errors
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());

    // redirect if not logged in or not enough permissions
    echo "<script>top.location=\"".$loginUrl."\";</script>";die;

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, and I am successfully authenticating the account & permissions, then I get redirected to the same page with a get vars "state" & "code", but it never shows as logged-in so my guess would be I am missing a config or something related to sessions.

Comment: What do you get when you dump the value of $facebook->getUser();

Comment: If its not getting the user then it will always test false and redirect to the login screen.  Are you sure you are getting the screen to login and authorising the app with the relevant permissions? try removing the app from you FB settings page and re authorising the app.  You should then get the popup a request for required permissions and then be redirected to the link you specify in the code.  If you still get int(0) then update the code paste with more of the code.

Comment: After authenticating & redirecting back to page, I tried printing the error & it gives out: OAuthException An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Comment: Check out the following link, this doesn't sound to me, you should be able to get the user data with the above unless your requesting extra data or an api call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034813/facebook-uncaught-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-i

Comment: After long time of testing, and changing codes ...etc. turns out its a Firefox issue, After clearing all private data, everything works fine.

Comment: The code is all PHP so its server side, it must be an issue with cookies and sessions not something to do with Firefox as such.