# php facebook sdk doesn't create the user in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook-login

**Edited question:**

Im trying to make a facebook login plugin on my wordpress site using [this sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034813/facebook-uncaught-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-i?answertab=active#tab-top)

When I click on  the facebook button to login or register it opens a small window via facebook that says continue but after than it doesnt create the user in wordpress database and breaking the wordpress footer, so it shows `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` messagge under the login form after the page refresh.

My full facebook login php code is this one:

```
    <?php 
    include 'facebook/facebook.php';
    function gazi_fb_loginForm(){

            gazi_fb_error_message();

            gazi_fb_LoadScript();

            if(is_user_logged_in()==false){

            ?>

                <div class="facebook_wrapper">
                <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'images/facebook_or.png';?>" style="border:none; box-shadow:none;">
                <br>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="FBLogin();">

                <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'images/facebook_button.png';?>" alt="Fb Connect" title="Login with facebook" /></a></div>

            <?php 

            } 

        }



    function gazi_fb_LoadScript(){

         global $wpdb;

         $gazi_option=$wpdb->prefix."gazi_option";

         $path =  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);  // define path to link and scripts

        $pageURL = get_permalink();

        $sign = strpos($pageURL,'?')?'&':'?';

         //facebook app secret

    $qry1="SELECT value FROM $gazi_option WHERE fieldname='gazi_facebook_app_secret'";

    $facebook_app_secret = $wpdb->get_var($qry1);

    $qry2="SELECT value FROM $gazi_option WHERE fieldname='gazi_facebook_app_id'";

    $facebook_app_id = $wpdb->get_var($qry2);



         $facebook = new Facebook(array(

            'appId'     =>  $facebook_app_id,

            'secret'    => $facebook_app_secret,

            ));

        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $facebook_app_id; ?>',
      xfbml      : true,
        status     : true, 
       cookie     : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
 });


FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
}
          else {
            console.log('initiate FB login...');
            FB.login();
          }
});

FB.api('/me/feed',function(response){
           var idDiv=document.getElementById('result');
           idDiv.textContent=JSON.stringify(response);
  }); 
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function FBLogin(){
    FB.login(function(response){
        if(response.authResponse){
            window.location.href = "<?php echo $pageURL.$sign;?>option=fblogin";
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}

    </script>

        <?php

        }



    function gazi_fb_error_message(){

            if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){

                echo '<div class="'.$_SESSION['msg_class'].'">'.$_SESSION['msg'].'</div>';

                unset($_SESSION['msg']);

                unset($_SESSION['msg_class']);

            }

        }



    function gazi_fb_login_validate(){



        $path =  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);  // define path to link and scripts

        $pageURL = get_permalink();

        $sign = strpos($pageURL,'?')?'&':'?';



        if(isset($_REQUEST['option']) && $_REQUEST['option']  == "fblogin"){

         global $wpdb;

         $gazi_option=$wpdb->prefix."gazi_option";

         //facebook app secret

          $qry1="SELECT value FROM $gazi_option WHERE fieldname='gazi_facebook_app_secret'";

          $facebook_app_secret = $wpdb->get_var($qry1);

          $qry2="SELECT value FROM $gazi_option WHERE fieldname='gazi_facebook_app_id'";

          $facebook_app_id = $wpdb->get_var($qry2);

            $facebook   = new Facebook(array(

                'appId' => $facebook_app_id,

                'secret' => $facebook_app_secret,

                'cookie' => TRUE,

            ));

            $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

            if ($fbuser) {

                try {

                    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

                }

                catch (Exception $e) {

                    echo $e->getMessage();

                    exit();

                }

                if (!isset($user_profile['email'])) $user_profile['email'] = $user_profile['id'] . '@facebook.com';

                $user_fbid  = $fbuser;

                $user_email = $user_profile["email"];

                $user_fnmae = $user_profile["first_name"];



              if( email_exists( $user_email )) { // user is a member 

                  $user = get_user_by('login', $user_email );

                  $user_id = $user->ID;


                  wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );

               } else { // this user is a guest

                  $random_password = wp_generate_password( 10, false );

                  $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_email, $random_password, $user_email );

                  update_user_meta($user_id, 'avtar_image', 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $user_profile['id'] . '/picture?type=large');

                  wp_update_user(array(

                              'ID' => $user_id,

                              'display_name' => $user_profile['name'],

                              'first_name' => $user_profile['first_name'],

                              'last_name' => $user_profile['last_name']

                            ));

                  wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );

               }



                wp_redirect( $pageURL.$sign.'login4=1');

                exit;



            }       

        }

    }

    ?>
```

here is the javascript in above code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $facebook_app_id; ?>',
      xfbml      : true,
        status     : true, 
       cookie     : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
 });


FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
}
          else {
            console.log('initiate FB login...');
            FB.login();
          }
});

FB.api('/me/feed',function(response){
           var idDiv=document.getElementById('result');
           idDiv.textContent=JSON.stringify(response);
  }); 
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function FBLogin(){
    FB.login(function(response){
        if(response.authResponse){
            window.location.href = "<?php echo $pageURL.$sign;?>option=fblogin";
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}

        </script>
```

Does any one know how ti make it working? What Im doing wrong?Any help is very appreciated.

Thankyou.

**UPDATE:**

I have changed some lines in my file using this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034813/facebook-uncaught-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-i?answertab=active#tab-top)

Changed this:
                $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

```
            if ($fbuser) {

                try {

                    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

                }

                catch (Exception $e) {

                    echo $e->getMessage();

                    exit();

                }
```

to this one:

```
$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

$photo_details = array('message' => 'my place');
$file='photos/my.jpg'; //Example image file
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

if ($fbuser) {
  try {
    // We have a valid FB session, so we can use 'me'
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
```

I got registered now but its very strange

the username and nick name of wordpress is allways @facebook :D

So I think its not getting the variables here:

```
if (!isset($user_profile['email'])) $user_profile['email'] = $user_profile['id'] . '@facebook.com'; and just keeping @facebook instead without the `$user_profile['id']`
```

Comment: try onclick instead of onClick.

Comment: thanks for your answer, eyvallah, but no luck its the same when I click on the button nothing happens again and same error in console.

Comment: I have no possibility of running the code right now but it might be out of scope as well.

Comment: yes the code as I told you is the sdk on the link in my question. and the above codes are getting my api id and keys from database so all are correct the only problem is this error. :(

Comment: Thankyou Ozan I changed the js code with another one which I got in facebook and reference error has been resolved but I have changed my question again :(

Comment: @Gazi I think you are missing the part that uses the access token provided by facebook. So you have no user context at all.

Comment: thanks Thomas but I realy don't know how to complete it.

Comment: I don't know how I did but yesterday was searching around and I got registering an user with username facebook and nickname facebook but I dont remember anymore how I did it :) so would be nice if someone can help me to complete this file

Answer (score 1):

Please find the sample code below. I have made the use of JavaScript SDK for the login and PHP SDK for generating access-token. I hope it will work for you.

** HTML Code:: **

```
    <html>

    <body>

  <p><a href="#" onClick="logInWithFacebook()">Log In with the JavaScript SDK</a></p>

  <script>
    logInWithFacebook = function() {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          alert('You are logged in &amp; cookie set!');
          location.href = "//localhost/facebook/testfb.php"
            // Now you can redirect the user or do an AJAX request to
            // a PHP script that grabs the signed request from the cookie.
        } else {
          alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      });
      return false;
    };
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: 'app-id',
        cookie: true, // This is important, it's not enabled by default
        version: 'v2.9'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

** PHP Code **

```
<?php
require_once('Facebook/autoload.php');
# /js-login.php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '{app-id}',
'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
]);

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();


try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}


if (!isset($accessToken)) {
    echo 'No cookie set or no OAuth data could be obtained from cookie.';
    exit;
}



// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);


// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('{app-id}'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email', $accessToken->getValue());
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
echo 'Email: ' . $user['email'];

?>
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply but I dont have autoload.php since Im using only this one https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk Im doing wrong?