# how to find graph URL for a page when http://graph.facebook.com/pagename doesn't work?

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-graph-api

For most (all?) Facebook pages, I can access its graph data by getting the last part of its URL and adding it to http://graph.facebook.com.  For example, http://graph.facebook.com/AKON pulls up data for http://www.facebook.com/AKON.

However, here's a page that doesn't work like that:

http://www.facebook.com/codblackops

Instead, http://graph.facebook.com/codblackops returns False.

What gives?  And is there any way to figure out the correctly graph address from the www.facebook.com/codblackops page (or page source)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a page returns false then it is either because you're missing access_token privileges or due to geographical restrictions.

---

In order to make an access token that does not expire you can use the following question as a guideline: [Do Facebook Oauth 2.0 Access Tokens Expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687770/do-facebook-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-expire)

Comment: it appears to be requiring the access token.  on the doc page FB has an example with an access token in it: access_token=2227470867|2.AQA9I9hTXD1GX_cI.3600.1314784800.0-100002218899081|bgQcIrFH_k_elp0Jz_LK2Gfpih0  ... will this persist?   i read somewhere that access tokens expire. (BTW, this access token does reveal the graph data for codblackops)

Comment: No access tokens do expire. You can request some that have an offline_access token. Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687770/do-facebook-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-expire It has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is even I have no access to that site. It's probably private/hidden, because it's redirecting me to the homepage. Check permissions and try again