# Get valid access token to post on facebook website status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Tried with an access token with graph API explorer and that works fine, but of course that one is just valid for a few hours. So how can I generate my own one?

Note: Want to write from an external website ( connected server and client side JS to FB ) on a Facebook Website of a club ( not the personal one!! )

Answer (score -1):

You have to make an app on facebook for your website. After that you sould authorize all of your visitors, and in scope parameters add `offline_access`. `offline_access` gives affect to access token live but it doesn't available anymore. I just found in here [removal offline_access](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

Comment: You might want to clarify: `offline_access gives affect to access token liv`, as it's a little difficult to interpret.

Comment: maybe this can help answer about access token live [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687770/do-facebook-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-expire)

Comment: offline_access is not available any more.