# No refresh_token in OAuth 2.0 response

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am developing a Google Chrome extension and am using Boris Smus Oauth 2.0 library.

The authentication exchange completes, however, the problem I am having is that even though I specify access_type=offline during authorization, I never receive a refresh_token during the exchange, just access_token, expires_in and token_type.

My hunch is that this is because in my API access settings, OAuth2 is set up as a web application and web applications are not granted offline access. Does anyone know if this is correct or have been able to get it to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is very strange that a refresh_token is not given for offline access when I thought that was the entire point of a refresh_token. If you have any updates on this, please do share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem by adding the optional approval_prompt=force parameter in the authorization url. By default, approval_prompt is set to 'auto'. When it is set to 'force', the refresh token appears during the token exchange.

Comment: In my case it wasn't set to offline at all. It assumed offline when I used a mobile application client ID, then it stopped working (didn't assume offline) when I switched to using web client ID.

Answer (score 2):

For Google's OAuth Client you need to have **prompt=consent** in parameters to get the refresh_token every time,

As Google, do not provide refresh_token for subsequent logins. It **only provides refresh_token when User Allows the Access for the first time**.

For more info checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857806/5752311

Answer (score 0):

According to [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2), refresh_token is optional and is not supported in Implicit Grant and Client Credentials Grant.

Since you mentioned access_type=offline, I guess you are using Facebook API. The [Boris Smus document](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) chapter VARYING OAUTH IMPLEMENTATIONS also said that Facebook doesn't return refresh token.

Please also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687770/do-facebook-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-expire).